# why java can connect to mssql server which using self-sign certifcate, it works without importing certficate into jvm's truststore

Tags: java, ssl

My java program connects to mssql server which using self-sign certifcate , I did not even import this self sign certficate into jvm's truststore and but it works without any error, my question is why?

My understanding is if it is self-sign cerificate withou rootCA, I should manully import this self-sign cerificate into jvm's trustore

If a certificate is signed by trusted rootCA which usually by default already installed at jvm's truststore, so I could skip manully import step.

PS: I enable -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake here is the output snipet of ssl

```
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.743 CEST|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
    javax.net.ssl|WARNING|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.820 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:261|Unable to indicate server name
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.821 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
    javax.net.ssl|WARNING|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.829 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
    javax.net.ssl|WARNING|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.829 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
    javax.net.ssl|INFO|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.835 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.836 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.836 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.851 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.851 CEST|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:634|No session to resume.
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.852 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.855 CEST|ClientHello.java:653|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
    "ClientHello": {
      "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
      "random"              : "8F 89 C6 64 55 42 1D 68 11 27 C3 8A 2A B4 82 42 E7 7A E7 46 02 DB 85 51 A1 C1 91 41 5D 4B 41 0B",
      "session id"          : "B2 F7 8F 58 B1 08 17 02 35 08 96 67 05 6D 71 FA 12 D4 35 4E 87 E7 82 5A 69 F4 A3 72 DE 72 E5 E3",
      "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.907 CEST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:401|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 DF F2 5A 5B 8C DF 4B   49 FD 83 98 8C 98 58 7D  ...Z[..KI.....X.
    0010: 4F E1 15 F7 8C 6A BD DE   06 86 8E 65 7D A5 08 4F  O....j.....e...O
    0020: 9E E1 94 FB B9 71 EF ED   90 E7 B8 69 45 3F 78 B7  .....q.....iE?x.
    0030: FD 21 89 CB F4 9C 31 ED   C3 C7 FA 73 14 71 92 95  .!....1....s.q..
    0040: 8A                                                 .
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.930 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.930 CEST|Finished.java:398|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 70 7C 5F C4 A0 99 63 4B   B5 63 E1 CD
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.933 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:149|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.935 CEST|Finished.java:535|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: D2 A0 06 FA 35 21 2B E1   5B 15 CA 15
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.937 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:479|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.938 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1578|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.938 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1597|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.938 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1625|wait for close_notify or alert
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.938 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:736|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|ALL|11|agroal-11|2021-05-13 10:31:51.938 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1633|discard plaintext while waiting for close (
contentType: 0/majorVersion: 0/minorVersion: 0/recordEpoch: -1/recordSN: 0xffffffffffffffff/fragment: null
)
```

Comment: But are you using SSL? or plaintext?

Comment: Yes, it uses ssl connection.

Comment: Show your code, including the JDBC URL string and all options.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is completely and utterly illegible. Edit it into your question. And please post more of the SSL debug trace, especially the rest of the `ClientHello` and the `Certificate` messages.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I put those infomration as you suggested

Comment: So the server didn't send a certificate? That means you must have enabled anonymous cipher suites.

Comment: I did nothing, i also dont know how to enable anoymous cipher suites on my side.